# Find the values of $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the equation $x^2-|x|=mx(x+1)$ has exactly $3$ real and distinct solutions.

Tags: functions, quadratics, absolute-value

Consider the equation:

$$x^2 - |x| = m x (x+1)$$

where $m \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to find the set $M$:

$$M=\{ m \in \mathbb{R} | \text{the equation has exactly $3$ real and distinct roots} \}$$

This is what I tried:

$$x^2 - |x| = m x (x+1)$$

$$x^2 - |x| - m x (x+1) = 0$$

This is equivalent to finding the solutions of the equation $f(x) = 0$, where we have:

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{2cm} f(x) = x^2 - |x| - mx(x+1)$$

And we need to find $m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ has exactly $3$ real and distinct solutions.

We have:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x^2-x-mx^2-mx & x \ge 0 \\
      x^2+x-mx^2-mx & x < 0 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      (1-m)x^2-(1+m)x & \ge 0 \\
      (1-m)x^2 +(1-m)x & x < 0 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$

I don't know how to continue from here. I have to find the set of values of $m$ such that we have $3$ real and distinct solutions for $f(x) = 0$. I think that means we would have $2$ real and distinct solutions for one branch of the above piece-wise function and $1$ solution for the other branch of the function, but I don't know how to use that reasoning to find $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can rewrite $x^2$ as $|x|^2$ then you can go somehow a little bit easy, because one root is $x=0$ then you can take two way of $x>0 ,x<0$
 if you think twice   $x=-1 $ is always one of roots.  so you need to find other root.

$$x^2 - |x| = m x (x+1)\\
|x|^2 - |x| = m x (x+1)\\
|x|(|x|-1)   = m x (x+1)\\x\neq 0 \\
\pm \not x(|x|-1)   = m \not x (x+1)$$ I think it easy to solve an eaution with degree one rather than degree two...
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lgeokgpnqj

another point of view is to use draw left-hand side as a function and right-hand side as a function too in one coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$ x=0$ is always a root.

the other roots satisfy
$$x\pm 1 =mx +m$$

or
$$(m-1)x=\pm 1 -m$$